# php sockets / tcp sockets

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

Can someone explain what really happens when we create a socket like :

`$socket  = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 1);`  and

`socket_send($socket, $package, strLen($package), 0);` .

What really happens at the Operating System Level (behind the scene) ?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of sockets is that you don't have to know about what is going on behind the scene. Hence the name -- Socket API.
If you really must know then turn to the sources, let's say FreeBSD, because I'm not sure about Windows sources.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets#References and more specifically http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/Networks/Intro/NetIntro.pdf